# Sorting a list of lists by the seconds element

Tags: list, sorting, haskell, compare

I'm having a hard time when I try to order a list of lists by the second element, something like this

```
list = [[_,B,_,_,_],[_,A,_,_,_],[_,C,_,_,_]]
```

into this:

```
list = [[_,A,_,_,_],[_,B,_,_,_],[_,C,_,_,_]]
```

I've tried:

```
sortBy compare $ [([1,2]!!1),([2,3]!!1)]
```

But it filters the seconds elements and order that into `[2,3]`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you tried to do is sort the list `[([1,2]!!1),([2,3]!!1)]`, which is equivalent to `[2, 3]`, by `compare`. What you *want* to do is use `sortBy` with a function that first gets the second element and then compares:

```
sortBySecond = sortBy (\ a b -> compare (a !! 1) (b !! 1))
```

Then take the list you have and apply this function to it:

```
sortBySecond [[1, 2], [2, 3]]
```

You can make this function neater by using `on` from `Data.Function`:

```
import Data.Function

sortBySecond = sortBy (compare `on` (!! 1))
```

You can also use `comparing` from `Data.Ord`:

```
sortBySecond = sortBy $ comparing (!! 1)
```

Comment: thanks for your help mate, i've tried your second option, because the first would only fit for 2 lists, but when i load the code i get this error:


Couldn't match expected type `a0 -> a0 -> Ordering'
                with actual type `Ordering'
    In the return type of a call of `compare'
    In the first argument of `sortBy', namely `(compare on (!! 1))'
    In the expression: sortBy (compare on (!! 1))

Comment: First of all, my two solutions are identical--both will work in exactly the same cases. Secondly, it's hard to see `\`` with the code formatting here, so did you write `compare \`on\` (!! 1)` or `compare on (!! 1)`?

Comment: you're right mate, i copied your code and the text editor put another character instead of the right one. now i can load the function but when i run "sortBySecond" i get this: 

"No instance for (Show ([[b0]] -> [[b0]]))
      arising from a use of `print'
    Possible fix:
      add an instance declaration for (Show ([[b0]] -> [[b0]]))
    In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it

Comment: It sounds like you did not specify the list to sort. Since you're in GHCi, you need to first type `let sortBySecond = ...` and then `sortBySecond [[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 0]]` (or whatever list you want to sort).

Comment: Binding it by `let sortBysecond = ...` in ghci is problematic. The monomorphism restriction will make ghci default it to `sortBySecond :: [[()]] -> [[()]]`. You can 1. bind itwith a signature, `let sortBySecond :: Ord a => [[a]] -> [[a]]; sotrBySecond = ...`, 2. bind with an argument, `let sortBySecond xs = ...`, 3. disable the MR, `:set -XNoMonomorphismRestriction` at the prompt.

Comment: i tried as you said and i get this when i try sortBySecond on [[1,2],[3,4]]

No instance for (Num ())
      arising from the literal `4'
    Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Num ())
    In the expression: 4
    In the expression: [3, 4]
    In the first argument of `sortBySecond', namely `[[1, 2], [3, 4]]'

Comment: Note that `comparing foo = compare 'on' foo`

Comment: @DanBurton: Cool, I did not know that. You can escape backticks in inline markup code with backslashes: `\\`on\\`` ==> `\`on\``.

Comment: @TikhonJelvis: Cool, I did not know that. :) `comparing foo = compare \`on\` foo`

Answer (score 0):

another idea I came up with would be to simply start sorting at the second element of a list by using `tail`. I also tried to write it point free - just as an exercise for me.

```
pfsortBySnd :: (Ord a) => [[a]] -> [[a]]
pfsortBySnd = sortBy second
            where second = comparing tail

sortBySnd :: (Ord a) => [[a]] -> [[a]]
sortBySnd xx = sortBy second xx
             where second x y = compare (tail x) (tail y)
```